# Partition size 128GB but only 64GB detected

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning

I used `dd` to copy an Ubuntu 18.04 installation from a 64GB partition on drive X to a 128GB partition on drive Y. See the below images for the problem; I am still limited to 64GB despite having a 128GB partition.

[From "Disks" (shows partition size)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qx92h.png)

[`df -h` result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vb3Ot.png)

[Baobab (aka Disk Usage Analyzer)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnQkC.png)

EDIT: Answer is below. I used `resize2fs` to grow the filesystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filesystem isn't configured to use the new size and needs to be manually "resized" after the device has grown (or before it's shrunk obviously).

Because this is an ext4 filesystem, you can run `resize2fs /dev/nvme0n1p3` to grow it online. (Other filesystem types have differently named tools and might need offline resizing.)